# Distance to the point of intersection of two altitudes in a triangle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, triangles, coordinate-systems

#### Problem

$P,Q,R$ are the points $(4,2)$, $(2,1)$ and $(6,-3)$. Also, $PS$ and $QT$ are altitudes in this triangle.

> A) Find the equations of PS and QT

My answer: PS: $y-x-2=0$, QT: $5y-2x-1=0$

> B) Hence find the coordinates of U, the point of intersection of PS and QT.

My answer: $(11/3, 5/3)$

> C) Find the length of PU as a surd in its simplest form

This I do not know how to do.

Comment: Altitudes of what, the triangle from these points? What does this have to do with math software?

Comment: it's nothing to do with maths software I just picked random tags

Comment: Well, a tag is used by people to filter questions they can answer. Randomly tagging is basically saying, "I can't be bothered."

Comment: You realize, once you post a question here, it is not "your question," it is a part of this site. This community  exists to give you answer, and to persist that question and answer beyond your personal needs. It is no longer your question, it is a stack exchange question.

Comment: If you don't want to observe the rules and comity of this site, you can go somewhere else. You have no right to cuss at me when I am trying to introduce you, a new user, on the rules and procedures.

Comment: ps i'm not a new user

Comment: Definitely a new account on Math.SE. Perhaps you've been here before under a different account. Maybe you were banned last time for rudeness? You are a classy one.

Comment: Actually no I have a new laptop so I am not on my other account lol

Comment: @user120243 I think your equation for PS is not right.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$PS\perp QR$$  So, the gradient of PS$(m_{PS})\cdot m_{QR}=-1$

Now, $$m_{QR}=\frac{-3-1}{6-2}$$

So, the equation of $PS$ will be $$\frac{y-2}{x-4}=m_{PS}$$

Now for $(C),$ do you know the distance between $$(x_1,y_1);(x_2,y_2)$$ is $$\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$$

Comment: What does that have to do with problem (C)?

Comment: yeah I don't need to know that I've done thart already, it's C i gotta do

Comment: @user120243, Its not clear from your Question that you could solve $A,B$. Please find the edited answer

Comment: omg thankyou so much lab bhattacharjee

Comment: I got the answer

Comment: @user120243, nice to hear that